# Merge duplicate table rows that are used in a relation with another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, sql-update, sql-delete

I have the following table structure:

```
table_a
id | customer_id | product_id
---+-------------+------
 1 | c1          | p1
 2 | c1          | p1
 3 | c2          | p1

table_b
id | table_a_id  | attribute
---+-------------+------
 99 | 1          | a1
 98 | 2          | a2
 97 | 3          | a3
```

As you can see `table_a` have duplicates values, and I want to merge them.
Unfortunatly the `table_a` `PK` is also used on `table_b`.

The final resoult should be:

```
table_a
id | customer_id | product_id
---+-------------+------
 1 | c1          | p1
 3 | c2          | p1

table_b
id | table_a_id  | attribute
---+-------------+------
 99 | 1          | a1
 98 | 1          | a2
 97 | 3          | a3
```

I have to update the `table_b` relation with `table_a`, and than clear all the unsed keys on `table_a`.

Unfortunatly the only query I've thought of is really heavy and the DB timeout before can be completed. `table_a` have 200k+ records and `table_b` is at least twice that.

My idea was:

- join `table_a` with `table_b` , to get: `(table_b_id, table_a_customer_id, table_a_product_id)`
- get the grouped up version of `table_a`. (to get the right `id` of `table_a` I just used `min("id")`
- inner join the two above and use the result to update `table_b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option using common table expressions:

```
with 
    ta as (
        select ta.*, min(id) over(partition by customer_id, product_id) min_id
        from table_a ta
    ),
    upd as (
        update table_b tb
        set table_a_id = ta.min_id
        from ta
        where tb.table_a_id = ta.id and ta.id <> ta.min_id
    )
delete from table_a ta1
using ta
where 
    ta1.customer_id = ta.customer_id
    and ta1.product_id = ta.product_id
    and ta1.id > ta.id
```

The first CTE associates the target `id` to each row of `table_a`. Then, we use that information to update `table_b`. Finally, we delete duplicate rows in `table_a`, retaining the earliest `id` only.